# user control object location after form maximized | c# - user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want to change the user control objects location after I maximize the form.
I tried the anchor and dock the user control, but the objects get out from the form (the resolution changed to height screen 900x1440)

there is any option to control the user control objects location after I maximize the form?

Comment: You can put it anywhere you want with the Resize event.  If that needs to only happen when it is maximized, but not when the user just makes it as big as the screen by dragging the edges (?), then pay attention to the WindowState property.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tableLayoutPanel , that will fit to your requirement.

Reference material:

"https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396"